# Omitting Memory Management attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

With the latest versions of xCode and LLVM compliers , it is possible to omit the memory management attributes when declaring properties etc,

`@property(copy) NSString *myString` can be declared as ,

```
@property NSString *myString;
```

Will the `myString` would use "`copy`" as the default attribute or "`Strong`" ?

Is there any place where can I find the default values ? etc. Will

`@property BOOL myBoolValue` will use `assign` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive data has no reference count, therefore you cannot use Strong or Weak with it, so you can only use assign, that is the default value

For objects, the default value in ARC is `strong`

Comment: My bad, but what would NSString will default to "Strong" or "copy" ??

Comment: If ARC, then it will be `strong`, if non-ARC `assign`.

Answer (score 0):

In projects that do not use `ARC` (and therefore use manual memory management) the default attributes for properties are `(atomic, assign)`. From Xcode 4.4+ (or 4.5+ I don't remember exactly which), in projects using ARC the default attributes are `(atomic, strong)`, though!

For NSStrings, therefore, it will also use strong, and not copy.

Check this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: The default is `atomic` not `nonatomic` according to this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

Object properties are strong by default.  Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html